# newline character does not work when parsing as JSON string object

Tags: javascript, html, json, string, knockout.js

I was having some trouble phrasing that title, but my problem is that the \n characters in strings in my JSON dictionary get nullified when I parse to html.

```js
var exp = {
"globalRunInfo" : {
  "file" : "file/path/goes/here", 
    "info" : "random junk here",
    "copyright" : "this is where I am getting my problem \n the newline doesn't work \n so all this gets formatted as one line"
   }
}

ko.applyBindings(exp);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

<div data-bind="with: globalRunInfo">
  <p data-bind="text: file"></p>
  <p>SOMETHING</p> 
  <p data-bind="text: info"></p>
  <span data-bind="text: copyright"></span>
</div>

</html>
```

Does anyone know how to fix this? I'm trying to avoid writing a function that checks for newline characters and replaces them with breaks or something. It's a lot of work for something that I'm going to use once.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try setting the CSS property `white-space: pre-wrap` on the `span` element. This will result in the braking of the new line character.

```
<span style="white-space: pre-wrap" data-bind="text: copyright"></span>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can assign a class to the area and use `white-space: pre-wrap`

Taken from the [**white-space documentation**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/white-space?v=control#Values):

```
pre-wrap
Sequences of whitespace are preserved. Lines are broken at newline characters, at <br>, and as necessary to fill line boxes.
```

In addition you can also remove the extra space after `\n` so you don't get the space added to the front of the new line.

```js
var exp = {
"globalRunInfo" : {
  "file" : "file/path/goes/here", 
    "info" : "random junk here",
    "copyright" : "this is where I am getting my problem \nthe newline doesn't work \nso all this gets formatted as one line"
   }
}

ko.applyBindings(exp);
```

```css
.example{
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

<div data-bind="with: globalRunInfo">
  <p data-bind="text: file"></p>
  <p>SOMETHING</p> 
  <p data-bind="text: info"></p>
  <span class="example" data-bind="text: copyright"></span>
</div>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

wrap the whole json text with pre tag. it worked with me